# Compact rephrasing of "In contrast to previous work, our method ...."

Tags: synonyms, expression-choice

I am writing an abstract for a paper, where I say the following:

> "**In contrast to previous work**, our method does not rely on ...."

Then, about three sentences later, I would like to use a similar construct

> "**In contrast to previous work**, where problem X is usually approached this way ...."

These constructs are useful to quickly highlight the contributions of your work in the abstract, but I would prefer avoiding the repetition of the exact same words, since the two sentences are close enough to each other in the text.

Can anybody think of a **compact** way of rephrasing either of these two sentences (without changing the structure of the text much) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a bit more context, it's hard to say how good a fit it would be, but something like

> **Unlike prior efforts**, our method does not rely on...

Comment: That's excellent! Just to clarify, I did not provide more context mostly because I wanted constructs that were not context-aware (i.e. as general as possible). Thanks!

Comment: Language isn't "general"; it's all in the context.

Comment: @AmV - glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Other possibilities

> **Our method introduces the element of**....

or even

> **We pioneer the use of...**